# Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Why is children.length resulting in **Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')** especially since the value of children.length is successfully displayed on the console?

```js
const getParentId = (childId) => {
    var queue = [ds]
    while(queue.length > 0){
      const children = queue[0].children
      queue.push(children)
      console.log("children.length = "+children.length)
      for (let i = 0; i < children.length; i++){
        if (children[i].id === childId) {return queue[0].id}
      }
      queue.shift()
    }
  }

  const addSiblingNodes = async () => {


    const child = [...selectedNodes][0]
    const childId = child.id
    const newNodes = getNewNodes()

    await dsDigger.addSiblings(childId, newNodes);
    setDS({ ...dsDigger.ds });
    
    console.log("the parent of "+childId +" is "+ getParentId(childId))
  };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `while` loop continues to loop after an entry in `queue` has no `children` property - the code actually pushes `undefined` onto `queue`. When it goes to report the length of `undefined` *on the next line* it throws the error causing the promise rejection.

Correct me if I'm wrong, but wouldn't it be true to say that no `children` array has a `children` property because only `child` nodes have `children` properties? If this is indeed true, the error is occuring on the second iteration of the `while` loop.

I suggest reviewing the design of `getParentId` because it seems to be attempting a branch walk of eldest children starting from the `ds` node - and possibly should be conducting a tree walk of all child branches.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! The real issue was in the question you posed.
`queue.push(children)` should be something like  `children.forEach(child => queue.push(child))`  In English, I was setting the next queue item to a list instead of actual nodes. Also, my design of getParentId seems to be equivalent to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/1616365/17011629