# Extracting all overlapping substrings between nested matching parentheses with a .NET regex

Tags: c#, regex, algorithm, nsregularexpression, qregularexpression

I'm trying to parse mathematical expressions with nested brackets:

```
(1 * (2 - 3)) + 4
```

I want to get every expression in brackets, like this:

- `(1 * (2 - 3))`
- `(2 - 3)`

Using this expression: `(.*?\))(?=($|[^(]+))` I'm getting this result:

```
(1 * (2 - 3)

)
```

And using this expression: `\(.*?\)` I'm getting this result:

```
(1 * (2 - 3)
```

But nothing works correctly. How can I loop an expression inside?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```cs
(?=(\((?>[^()]+|(?<c>)\(|(?<-c>)\))*(?(c)(?!))\)))
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3D%28%5C%28%28%3F%3E%5B%5E%28%29%5D%2B%7C%28%3F%3Cc%3E%29%5C%28%7C%28%3F%3C-c%3E%29%5C%29%29*%28%3F%28c%29%28%3F!%29%29%5C%29%29%29&i=%281%20*%20%282%20-%203%29%29%20%2B%204). *Details*:

- `(?=` - a positive lookahead:

  - `(\((?>[^()]+|(?<c>)\(|(?<-c>)\))*(?(c)(?!))\)))` - Group 1:

    - `\(` - a `(` char
    - `(?>[^()]+|(?<c>)\(|(?<-c>)\))*` - zero or more repetitions of any one or more chars other than `(` and `)`, or a `(` char (with a value pushed onto Group "c" stack), or a `)` char (with a value popped from the Group "c" stack)
    - `(?(c)(?!))` - if Group "c" stack is not empty, fail and backtrack
    - `\)` - a `)` char.

See the [C# demo](https://ideone.com/VHuGYb):

```cs
var text = "(1 * (2 - 3)) + 4";
var pattern = @"(?=(\((?>[^()]+|(?<c>)\(|(?<-c>)\))*(?(c)(?!))\)))";
var results = Regex.Matches(text, pattern)
    .Cast<Match>()
    .Select(m => m.Groups[1].Value)
    .ToList();
Console.WriteLine(String.Join(", ", results));
// => (1 * (2 - 3)), (2 - 3)
```

Comment: interesting this works well when I run it in Linqpad, but in RegexBuddy it fails to match even though it compiles fine

Comment: @gordy Do not use it in Regex*, use it in C#. This is a .NET compliant regex.

Answer (score -2):

The usual way would be to use a [recursive regular expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26385984/recursive-pattern-in-regex) but unfortunately this capability is not supported by C#'s Regex. Alternatively, you can manually parse the string (and there is C# code provided [in this PAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6606290/99691) to do that).

Comment: Please don't link to existing answers like this. If this question is a duplicate of the other, then mark it as so.

Comment: @Enigmativity is there a community guideline for this? it's not a duplicate question since they asked specifically how to do this via regex but the answer is probably relevant - I thought linking would be better than copying and pasting the answer here since the context is probably also useful

Comment: Unless you have something substantive in your answer (i.e. it can stand alone) then it should be a comment. Does "C#'s Regex doesn't support recursive expressions, I suggest parsing this manually" answer this question?

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265552/when-to-flag-an-answer-as-not-an-answer